# How to create a Model for a map of map , multilevel map in Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i have the multi-level Json which i would want to create a model for  found in https://blockchain.info/ticker

here is what i did bit doesnt help in serializing it to a list, like i can not access the outter and inner Maps:

````
 final double delay;
 final double recentMarketPprice;
 final double buyPrice;
 final double sellPrice;
 final String symbol;

 BitRateValues(
      {this.delay,
 this.recentMarketPprice,
 this.buyPrice,
 this.sellPrice,
 this.symbol});

 factory BitRateValues.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
 return BitRateValues(
        delay: data['15m'],
        recentMarketPprice: data['last'],
        buyPrice: data['buy'],
        sellPrice: data['sell'],
        symbol: data['symbol']);
  }
}

class BitRateMAp {
 Map<String, BitRateValues> bits;
 BitRateMAp({this.bits});
}```

please kinldy help
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I recommend putting all relevant code and data samples in your question next time. So that if the API changes, URLs get broken etc. the question and the answers can still be used by future readers.

All of those currencies are JSON objects ("USD", "AUD" etc.) and not an array... So you will have to declare them all in order to consume that JSON.

JSON:

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 10956.55, "last" : 10956.55, "buy" : 10956.55, "sell" : 10956.55, "symbol" : "$"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 15023.62, "last" : 15023.62, "buy" : 15023.62, "sell" : 15023.62, "symbol" : "$"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 59143.45, "last" : 59143.45, "buy" : 59143.45, "sell" : 59143.45, "symbol" : "R$"},
  "CAD" : {"15m" : 14461.13, "last" : 14461.13, "buy" : 14461.13, "sell" : 14461.13, "symbol" : "$"},
  "CHF" : {"15m" : 9982.46, "last" : 9982.46, "buy" : 9982.46, "sell" : 9982.46, "symbol" : "CHF"},
  "CLP" : {"15m" : 8363136.86, "last" : 8363136.86, "buy" : 8363136.86, "sell" : 8363136.86, "symbol" : "$"},
  "CNY" : {"15m" : 74164.87, "last" : 74164.87, "buy" : 74164.87, "sell" : 74164.87, "symbol" : "¥"},
  "DKK" : {"15m" : 68828.23, "last" : 68828.23, "buy" : 68828.23, "sell" : 68828.23, "symbol" : "kr"},
  "EUR" : {"15m" : 9252.82, "last" : 9252.82, "buy" : 9252.82, "sell" : 9252.82, "symbol" : "€"},
  "GBP" : {"15m" : 8472.15, "last" : 8472.15, "buy" : 8472.15, "sell" : 8472.15, "symbol" : "£"},
  "HKD" : {"15m" : 84913.79, "last" : 84913.79, "buy" : 84913.79, "sell" : 84913.79, "symbol" : "$"},
  "INR" : {"15m" : 805690.37, "last" : 805690.37, "buy" : 805690.37, "sell" : 805690.37, "symbol" : "₹"},
  "ISK" : {"15m" : 1490967.05, "last" : 1490967.05, "buy" : 1490967.05, "sell" : 1490967.05, "symbol" : "kr"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 1145199.68, "last" : 1145199.68, "buy" : 1145199.68, "sell" : 1145199.68, "symbol" : "¥"},
  "KRW" : {"15m" : 1.276426884E7, "last" : 1.276426884E7, "buy" : 1.276426884E7, "sell" : 1.276426884E7, "symbol" : "₩"},
  "NZD" : {"15m" : 16212.46, "last" : 16212.46, "buy" : 16212.46, "sell" : 16212.46, "symbol" : "$"},
  "PLN" : {"15m" : 41210.73, "last" : 41210.73, "buy" : 41210.73, "sell" : 41210.73, "symbol" : "zł"},
  "RUB" : {"15m" : 828134.25, "last" : 828134.25, "buy" : 828134.25, "sell" : 828134.25, "symbol" : "RUB"},
  "SEK" : {"15m" : 96075.78, "last" : 96075.78, "buy" : 96075.78, "sell" : 96075.78, "symbol" : "kr"},
  "SGD" : {"15m" : 14887.32, "last" : 14887.32, "buy" : 14887.32, "sell" : 14887.32, "symbol" : "$"},
  "THB" : {"15m" : 340419.95, "last" : 340419.95, "buy" : 340419.95, "sell" : 340419.95, "symbol" : "฿"},
  "TRY" : {"15m" : 82859.99, "last" : 82859.99, "buy" : 82859.99, "sell" : 82859.99, "symbol" : "₺"},
  "TWD" : {"15m" : 317959.03, "last" : 317959.03, "buy" : 317959.03, "sell" : 317959.03, "symbol" : "NT$"}
}
```

DART:

```
class AllCurrencies {
  Currency uSD;
  Currency aUD;
  Currency bRL;
  Currency cAD;
  Currency cHF;
  Currency cLP;
  Currency cNY;
  Currency dKK;
  Currency eUR;
  Currency gBP;
  Currency hKD;
  Currency iNR;
  Currency iSK;
  Currency jPY;
  Currency kRW;
  Currency nZD;
  Currency pLN;
  Currency rUB;
  Currency sEK;
  Currency sGD;
  Currency tHB;
  Currency tRY;
  Currency tWD;

  AllCurrencies(
      {this.uSD,
        this.aUD,
        this.bRL,
        this.cAD,
        this.cHF,
        this.cLP,
        this.cNY,
        this.dKK,
        this.eUR,
        this.gBP,
        this.hKD,
        this.iNR,
        this.iSK,
        this.jPY,
        this.kRW,
        this.nZD,
        this.pLN,
        this.rUB,
        this.sEK,
        this.sGD,
        this.tHB,
        this.tRY,
        this.tWD});

  AllCurrencies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uSD = json['USD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['USD']) : null;
    aUD = json['AUD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['AUD']) : null;
    bRL = json['BRL'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['BRL']) : null;
    cAD = json['CAD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['CAD']) : null;
    cHF = json['CHF'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['CHF']) : null;
    cLP = json['CLP'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['CLP']) : null;
    cNY = json['CNY'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['CNY']) : null;
    dKK = json['DKK'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['DKK']) : null;
    eUR = json['EUR'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['EUR']) : null;
    gBP = json['GBP'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['GBP']) : null;
    hKD = json['HKD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['HKD']) : null;
    iNR = json['INR'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['INR']) : null;
    iSK = json['ISK'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['ISK']) : null;
    jPY = json['JPY'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['JPY']) : null;
    kRW = json['KRW'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['KRW']) : null;
    nZD = json['NZD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['NZD']) : null;
    pLN = json['PLN'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['PLN']) : null;
    rUB = json['RUB'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['RUB']) : null;
    sEK = json['SEK'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['SEK']) : null;
    sGD = json['SGD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['SGD']) : null;
    tHB = json['THB'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['THB']) : null;
    tRY = json['TRY'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['TRY']) : null;
    tWD = json['TWD'] != null ? new Currency.fromJson(json['TWD']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.uSD != null) {
      data['USD'] = this.uSD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.aUD != null) {
      data['AUD'] = this.aUD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.bRL != null) {
      data['BRL'] = this.bRL.toJson();
    }
    if (this.cAD != null) {
      data['CAD'] = this.cAD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.cHF != null) {
      data['CHF'] = this.cHF.toJson();
    }
    if (this.cLP != null) {
      data['CLP'] = this.cLP.toJson();
    }
    if (this.cNY != null) {
      data['CNY'] = this.cNY.toJson();
    }
    if (this.dKK != null) {
      data['DKK'] = this.dKK.toJson();
    }
    if (this.eUR != null) {
      data['EUR'] = this.eUR.toJson();
    }
    if (this.gBP != null) {
      data['GBP'] = this.gBP.toJson();
    }
    if (this.hKD != null) {
      data['HKD'] = this.hKD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.iNR != null) {
      data['INR'] = this.iNR.toJson();
    }
    if (this.iSK != null) {
      data['ISK'] = this.iSK.toJson();
    }
    if (this.jPY != null) {
      data['JPY'] = this.jPY.toJson();
    }
    if (this.kRW != null) {
      data['KRW'] = this.kRW.toJson();
    }
    if (this.nZD != null) {
      data['NZD'] = this.nZD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.pLN != null) {
      data['PLN'] = this.pLN.toJson();
    }
    if (this.rUB != null) {
      data['RUB'] = this.rUB.toJson();
    }
    if (this.sEK != null) {
      data['SEK'] = this.sEK.toJson();
    }
    if (this.sGD != null) {
      data['SGD'] = this.sGD.toJson();
    }
    if (this.tHB != null) {
      data['THB'] = this.tHB.toJson();
    }
    if (this.tRY != null) {
      data['TRY'] = this.tRY.toJson();
    }
    if (this.tWD != null) {
      data['TWD'] = this.tWD.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Currency {
  double d15m;
  double last;
  double buy;
  double sell;
  String symbol;

  Currency({this.d15m, this.last, this.buy, this.sell, this.symbol});

  Currency.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    d15m = json['15m'];
    last = json['last'];
    buy = json['buy'];
    sell = json['sell'];
    symbol = json['symbol'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['15m'] = this.d15m;
    data['last'] = this.last;
    data['buy'] = this.buy;
    data['sell'] = this.sell;
    data['symbol'] = this.symbol;
    return data;
  }
}
```